# Creating a histogram in R that shows the difference in the number of errors made by three groups

Tags: r, histogram

I have to create a histogram in RStudio with the number of errors of three (3) Data groups. There are GroupA, GroupB and GroupC. Each one of them has 4 variables and one of them is the "errors" variable. So its like GroupA$errors etc..

How am I going to combine these 3 Groups and make a plot on which on the x axis shows 3 bars (each one of them is each group) and on the y axis the number of errors?

dput: http://pastebin.com/vGEPDNFf

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hn2mWwr.png

Comment: Try `dput` and add the output to your question, then we can just put that directly in our own R session.

Comment: I added the dput command output to my question.

Comment: You need to call `dput` on your data, not just type it.  Try `dput(myData)`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vGEPDNFf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data:

```
myData <- data.frame(case = 1:48,
                     group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                     age = c(70,68,61,68,77,72,64,65,69,67,71,75,73,68,65,69,63,70,78,73,76,78,65,68,75,65,62,69,70,71,60,69,60,66,75,70,62,63,79,79,66,76,64,61,70,67,69,63),
                     errors = c(9,6,7,8,10,11,4,5,5,6,12,8,9,3,7,6,8,6,12,7,13,10,8,8,11,5,9,6,9,6,9,7,5,3,6,6,7,5,9,8,6,6,3,4,7,5,4,5))
```

Here is the code you have to run in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(total.errors=sum(errors)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(group), y=total.errors)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

It gives you the following figure:[image]

Comment: what should I include in the function? eg. mtcars <- ?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with your data. I had used mtcars as an illustration. Is everything clear for you now? myData is grouped then summarized with "a sum of errors by group" then it is plotted. More info about the functions and the pipe (%>%) here http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf